# How to switch versions of iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Now that I installed SDK 3.2 for my iPad development, I need to build with the previous version for my old iTouch.  Is this possible to switch or do I have to uninstall 3.2, install 3.1.x and re-install 3.2 in a "versioned" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to build settings (right click on your project and click info) you can set the base sdk for the project. the setting is right up the top of the list. if you set it back to 3.0 (for example) then you can choose all releases from then till now.

Comment: How about installing different versions on your devices?

Comment: installing different versions is fine as long as your device is above or equal to the sdk you are trying to install. I can build and run 3.0 on my iPhone which is up to 3.1.3 (man this comment will date fast :)

Comment: mulholland ... that was subtle but easy.  I am up and running again.  thanks a million.